# c++11: subtlety of std::forward: Is identity really necessary?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++11

I set up a test case to learn about perfect forwarding.

```
std::string inner(const std::string& str ) {
return "const std::string&";
}
std::string inner(std::string& str ) {
    return "std::string&";
}
std::string inner(const std::string&& str ) {
    return "const std::string&&";
}
std::string inner(std::string&& str ) {
    return "std::string&&";
}

template <typename T> void outer(T&& t) {
  std::cout << "t: " << t << std::endl;
  std::cout << "perfect forward: " << inner(std::forward<T>(t)) << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

void PerfectForwarding()
{
     outer("literal");
     outer(lvalue);
     outer(constlvalue);
     outer(rvalue());
     outer(constrvalue());
}
```

`std::forward` works as expected.  The interesting behavior emerges when I implement my own forward function without identity:

```
template <typename T> T&& MyForward(T& t)
{
   return ((T&&)t);
}
```

Replacing `std::forward` with `MyForward` in outer gives the exact same result!  The behavior begs the question why identity is used?

Compiler VS2010

Update 1: In reference to preventing type deduction

AFAIK, the special type deduction rule is only activated on T&&.  Note the definition of forward, `forward(typename identity<T>::type& t)`.  The argument type has only one &.  In fact, after I changed MyForward to use identity, and leave out the (T&&) casting, the example does not compile.  On the surface, the casting from lvalue to rvalue seems to make the forward work.

Update 2: tested on ideone.com with GCC 4.5, same behavior.

Comment: What do you mean by "identity"? The two overloads of the `std::forward` or the `remove_reference<T>::type`?

Comment: identity refers the identity struct, the type of forward's argument: _Ty&& forward(typename identity<_Ty>::type& _Arg)

Comment: That must be some pre-standard signature. The standard one is `T&& forward(typename remove_reference<T>::type& t)` (and an overload taking `&&`).

Comment: I use the VS2010 compiler.  it could be a compiler specific behavior.  cppreference.com does list two overloads of forward.

Comment: @Candy : VC++ 2010 was based on N3000, which came with `std::identity<>`; the final C++11 standard is based on N3290, which removed it.

Comment: @ildjarn I see.  Can you run my example in VC11 to see if you can replicate the behavior?

Comment: @Candy : I don't have VC11 handy, sorry, but I'm sure some other SO users do. :-]

Comment: I suspect they removed identity after asking the same question and coming to the same conclusion.

Comment: @AJG85: No, it was replaced with something similar. `identity` had a purpose.

Answer (score 14):

`remove_reference<T>` (`identity` was in an old version of the draft, but was changed to `remove_reference`) is used to prevent type deduction: `std::forward` *only* works with an explicit type parameter. Otherwise the following would compile:

```
std::forward(t)
```

... but it would not do the right thing.

Regarding the issue with lvalues/rvalues, please do notice that there are [*two overloads* of `std::forward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward): one for lvalues, another for rvalues.

In fact, the `MyForward` implementation given is more like [`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move): it turns lvalues into rvalues (the difference is that move accepts rvalues as well).

Comment: there's only one this VS2010.  And it works with one.  then why do we need two?

Comment: @CandyChiu it works on VS2010 because it was shipped before the standard was finalized. The rules have changed between the time VS2010 shipped and the standard was published. We need two because lvalues won't bind to `&&`, and rvalues won't bind to `&`.

Comment: I see.  Unfortunately, i don't have another compiler handy to test this.

Comment: @Candy if it helps, http://ideone.com runs GCC 4.5. I don't know how they implemented it there, but you can experiment with your own implementations. I believe it has the correct rvalue binding semantics.

Comment: I tried on ideone.com, save behavior: MyForward and std::forward gives same result.  However GCC 4.5 assigns type T& to literal value, while VC2010 assigns type const T&.

Comment: Well, guess 4.5 wasn't okay yet :( FWIW, I run both GCC 4.7 and clang 3.1 and it works as I described.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the definition of `forward` and `identity` in VS 2010. The only difference between your `MyForward` and their `forward` is that you use a `T&` parameter and they use a `typename identity<T>::type&` parameter. And the `identity<T>::type` is just `T`.

The most important (maybe also only) effect of this difference is that to use their `forward` the template argument must be explicitly specified while your `MyForward`'s template argument can be deduced from a call.

Comment: Yes, if pass an lvalue to outer(T&&), t will be cast to an rvalue reference type.